# Unable to retrieve a geopoint data field when searching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a field called `loc` which is correctly mapped as a geopoint.

When running a search like:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/DB/_search'
```

I get 10 or so results and all of them appear to have `loc` inside the `_source` object.

If I try:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/DB/_search?fields=name'
```

I get a `fields` object with the `name` field correctly set up (`name` exists, it is another field, it is a string). Thing is, if I try the same thing with the `loc` field, as in:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/DB/_search?fields=loc'
```

I don't get anything back, neither the `_source` nor the `fields` objects.

How may I return the `loc` field when running this query?

Bonus question: Is there a way to return the `loc` field as a geohash?

Update, here's the mapping:

```
{
  "geonames": {
    "mappings": {
      "place": {
        "properties": {
          "ele": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "geoid": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "loc": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "pop": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tz": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/DB/_mapping`?

Comment: can you try this instead (i.e. source filtering instead of fields)? `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/DB/_search?_source=loc'

Comment: With source filtering, it does work.

Comment: I guess the reason could be "geo_point" is not stored by default and cant be retrieved with `fields` could that be reason @Val?

Comment: @ChintanShah25, definitely.

Comment: I just tested this with 2.x and it worked with the `geo_point`, but Val's answer is the appropriate one nonetheless.

Comment: I am a bit confused here, how we can retrieve other things like `string` with `fields` as they are also not stored by default right, @Val?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Never thought of that, I thought they were stored by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead of [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) and you'll get the `loc` field as you expect.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/DB/_search?_source=loc'
```

Quoting from the official documentation on fields (emphasis added):

> The fields parameter is about fields that are explicitly marked as stored in the mapping, which is **off by default** and generally not recommended. Use source filtering instead to select subsets of the original source document to be returned.

Comment: Thanks val, nice insight, how may I turn on the mapping storage on that field? So that it appears on the fields object.

Comment: You can specify the `store` parameter [(view info)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) in your field mapping.

Comment: It's _not_ suggested to store fields unless you have a strong need. Most use cases will be fine with source filtering.